# javascript: how to retrieve file from cache?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sending out AJAX request for a XML file to plot a chart. The problem is everytime the response comes back, the chart refresh itself, even if the XML is exactly the same.

I would like to use Javascript to check the content of the reponse XML with the cached XML, and only push to the chart if there are changes, dont do anything if it's the same.

How do I retrieve the cached XML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i finally got it.

```
if (i != 0) // if not 1st run
   currentXML = newXML;

newXML = xmlhttp.responseText;
i = 1;

if (newXML != currentXML) // if XML content changes
{
  ...plot the chart...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some variable, for example `xmlString`. When you request new data, check whether `xmlString==response`. If yes, cancel. If not, save the response in `xmlString` and process it.

Comment: How do you set the xmlString to the current/cached XML?

Comment: this way: `xmlString = serversResponse`

Answer (score 0):

The approach mentioned by `thejh` is suited only if you have no control over the server code.

However if you are manning the server too, you need to ensure that the **server** keeps track of the changes in underlying information/parameters and sends the xml if and only if this data/parameter has changed. You'll **save** on **network bandwidth** and **increase performance**.

Comment: That would be great but no I don't really have full server access :|

Comment: Just to get my head around it, the xml is being is being received via calls made to an external web service and you do not have any control over the server code?